# Tab completion problem using start in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to open `[test].txt` in powershell, but when I press tab on keyboard, it autocompletes like this:

```
start '.\`[test`].txt'
```

and generates this error:

> start: Could not run this command due to error: The system cannot find the file specified.
> At line: 1 character: 1
> + start '.`[test`].txt'
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> + CategoryInfo: InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
> + FullQualifiedErrorId: InvalidOperationException, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

I want to remove the backtick characters when I press tab. How can I do this?

Comment: Use the `-LiteralPath` parameter to pass file names/paths containing wildcard characters, eg.: `Invoke-Item -LiteralPath '.\[test].txt'`. If that doesn't work, make sure you're in the right directory where the file exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69437886/45375).

What you're seeing is a **limitation in PowerShell's tab-completion** (up to at least PowerShell Core 7.2.0-preview.9):

- You're tab-completing a value for the - positionally implied - `-FilePath` parameter of the [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)  cmdlet (`start` is built-in alias for it).
- Since `-FilePath` only accepts *literal* (verbatim) file paths, *not* also wildcard patterns, tab-completion should result in `.\[test].txt`, *without* the `` ` ``-escaping of [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards)-pattern metacharacters `[` and `]`.

By contrast, [`Invoke-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/invoke-item) (whose built-in alias is `ii`) *does* support wildcard patterns via its `-Path` parameter - as well as *literal* (verbatim) paths via its `-LiteralPath` parameter:

- Since `-Path` is in `Invoke-Item's` *default* [parameter set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parameter_Sets) and is the first positional parameter, **the tab-completed value would have worked as-is had you used `Invoke-Item` rather than `Start-Process`**:

  ```
  # OK with tab-completion: positionally binds to -Path
  Invoke-Item '.\`[test`].txt'
  ```
- In fact, tab-completion is aware of when the argument at hand will be bound to a `-LiteralPath` parameter and then does *not* perform escaping:

  ```
  # OK with tab-completion: due to explicitly targeting -LiteralPath,
  # no escaping is performed.
  Invoke-Item -LiteralPath .\[test].txt
  ```
- The above applies to *all* [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) cmdlets, such as `Get-ChildItem` and `Get-Content` (roughly speaking, they comprise the cmdlets that have the word `Item`, `Content`, or `Property` in their name).

---

**Potential future enhancement:**

- PowerShell's tab-completion logic is currently hard-wired to:

  - default to *escaped* completion,
  - except if the target parameter name (if known) happens to be `-LiteralPath`
- [GitHub issue #14149](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14149) proposes:

  - defaulting to *literal* completion.
  - except if the target parameter (if known) explicitly signals support for wildcard patterns via the [`SupportsWildcardsAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.SupportsWildcardsAttribute)

---

**When to use `Start-Process` vs. `Invoke-Item`**:

- Simply put, **`Start-Process` is a *superset* of `Invoke-Item`**; the former is typically used to *launch GUI executables*, whereas the latter is typically used to *open documents* with the application registered to handle them or *directories* in File Explorer (on Windows).
- While `Start-Process` can do everything `Invoke-Item` can do *and more*, a **crucial difference** which amounts to a **pitfall** is that **`Start-Process` looks for a file or directory identified *by name only* in the directories listed in `$env:PATH` *first*** rather than *only* in the *current* directory; **prefixing the name with `.\`** (or using a full path) avoids this ambiguity.

```
# Unambiguously targets .\file.txt, i.e. a file in the *current* dir.
# In other words: The same as:
#   Invoke-Item .\file.txt
Invoke-Item file.txt

# AMBIGUOUS:
# !! *First* looks for a file.txt file in the directories
# !! listed in $env:PATH and opens the first one it finds.
# !! Only if none is found does it look in the current dir.
Start-Process file.txt

# OK - unambiguously looks in the current dir. only, thanks to ".\"
Start-Process .\file.txt
```

Note:

- Since **`Start-Process`** is typically used to *launch executables* (*GUI* executables; except for special situations, it is the wrong tool for launching *console* applications), **looking in `$env:PATH` (first) makes sense, but that the behavior also extends to *documents* (*non*-executables) is unexpected and problematic** - see [GitHub issue #9469](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9469).

On the plus side, **`Start-Process`** (unlike `Invoke-Item`) **can open *URLs*** in the default web browser; e.g.:

```
Start-Process http://example.org
```

**In summary**:

- It is fine to always use `Start-Process` in lieu of `Invoke-Item`, as long as you avoid ambiguity by prefixing target items in the *current* directory with `.\` - fortunately, tab-completion for items in the current dir. automatically adds this prefix.

Answer (score 0):

`start` (an alias for `Start-Process`) is really designed to launch executables or external commands.

For invoking the default shell handler associated with an arbitrary file, use `Invoke-Item` instead!

In order to avoid PowerShell attempting to interpret `[...]` as a wildcard pattern, use the `-LiteralPath` parameter:

```
Invoke-Item -LiteralPath '.\[test].txt'
```

All item provider cmdlets (`*-Item`, `*-ChildItem`) supports literal path binding, so it's always the best/safer choice when you have an exact path.